# LC3 Assembly - How do I toggle the lowest order bit in a binary number?

Tags: assembly, lc3

I was wondering if there was a way to toggle the low order bit in binary.

For example:

01000001 ->
Toggle Low Order Bit
-> 01000000

Changing the last bit on the right only. 
If you are unfamiliar with LC3 it only has the following operations:

- ADD
- AND
- NOT

Comment: Could you just AND RESULT, BITS, xFFFE ?

Comment: `and` will clear the bits, not toggle

Comment: boolean alegebra tells us: `a XOR b` := `(a AND (NOT b)) OR ((NOT a) AND b)` ( one of the bits is 1, and the other one 0)

Comment: That seems like a really annoying architecture to program on.  You have to spend a bunch of time figuring out how to do basic boolean operations like `XOR` or `OR` as well as figuring out which bits to test and branch on.

Answer (score 3):

This would typically be accomplished with a XOR, operation.

```
; field is R0
; R1 is mask of bits to toggle
; R2 is scratch
LD R0, #0b01000001
LD R1, #0b00000001
NOT R2, R0
AND R2, R2, R1
NOT R1, R1
AND R0, R0, R1
ADD R0, R0, R2
; result in R0
```

Comment: Your code works, but that's not [a bitwise NOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_logic).  The overall operation is [an XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate), so it flips every bit that's set in the mask.

Comment: @PeterCordes, True!  I'm not sure why I said NOR.  I was thinking XOR and even looking at an XOR truth table.

Answer (score 1):

If the lowest bit is 0, then you need to add 1.

If the lowest bit is 1, then you need to add -1.

So if input is *a*, then:

```
 x = a and 1    ; x = 0/1 depending on lowest bit
 x = x + x      ; x = 0/2
 x = not x      ; x = -1/-3
 x = x + 2      ; x = +1/-1
 r = a + x      ; will toggle lowest bit of original a
```

I assume the two's complement negative integer values is used in LC3, so `NOT 2 == -3`, and `-1 + 2 = +1`.

Unfortunately I don't know LC3, so I just hope my steps are reasonably simple to be implemented by LC3 instructions and the algorithm makes sense.

---

Other option is to use the `NOT` to toggle the bit (not addition):

```
 x = a and (not(1)) ; (0xFFFE in case of 16b word)
     ; x = copy of all bits of A except bottom bit (bottom bit = 0)
 y = not(a) and 1   ; extract toggled bottom bit (1/0)
 r = x + y          ; compose the value back from the upper:lowest bit(s)
```

edit: which is what Mitch does in his answer.

Comment: AFAIK, LC3's `add` instruction is unsigned binary (and thus also 2's complement signed).  Any other signed number format would need a separate signed-add instruction.  Or to put it another way, the number you need to add to clear the lowest bit if it's set is unsigned all-ones, like you get with C `unsigned`.

Comment: Using more constants may be a downside for LC3; I don't think it has immediate forms of anything.  But you could write (`~0-1`) more easily as `~1`.  That's @Mitch's implementation: ANDN both ways with a mask and ADD (as a replacement for OR) to bit-blend between `not(a)` and `a`.  (Exactly like you would blend elements with SSE2 AND/ANDN/OR when PBLENDVB isn't available.)

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, Mitch implementation is spot on and there's nothing to add to it. I still believe my answer may add some more background to OP, how it works, plus the "add" way idea... The (~0-1) is silly, I don't even know if OP understands C syntax... probably `not(1)` would be best in terms of LC3 question, will edit it.

Comment: Yeah, upvoted for an explanation of why it works.  I didn't really see exactly how Mitch's worked until reading yours.